# Prove a function $f: \mathbb{R}^{2} \to \mathbb{R}^{2}$ is surjective

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I'm given the map $f: (x,y) \mapsto (x+3,4-y): \mathbb{R}^{2} \to \mathbb{R}^{2}$; how do I prove this function is onto (surjective)?
So far I said that let $x=z$ and $y=k$,
therefore $f(x,y)=(z+3,4-k)$, that means $f(x,y)$ is onto (surjective).
I'm not sure if this is the way to prove a function is onto. Or does this mean that the function is not onto?? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $(z_{1},z_{2}) \in \mathbb{R}^{2}$; then $z_{1} = x+3$ and $z_{2} = 4-y$ for some $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^{2}$ iff $x = z_{1}-3$ and $y = 4-z_{2}$; this shows that for every point $(z_{1},z_{2})$ of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ there is some unique $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^{2}$ such that $(z_{1},z_{2}) = f(x,y)$, so $f$ is in fact bijective, and hence surjective.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the idea behind what you're doing.

For surjective, you need to pick an arbitrary $(z, w) \in \Bbb R^2$ (the range $\Bbb R^2$) and show that there's some $(x, y) \in \Bbb R^2$ (the domain $\Bbb R^2$) with $f(x, y)$ equal to your chosen pair $(z, w)$.

**If** this can happen, it means $$\underbrace{f(x, y) = (x + 3, 4 - y)}_{\text{definition of $f$}} \underbrace{= (z , w)}_{\text{what we want}}.$$

Can we find $x$ and $y$ so that $x + 3 = z$ and $4 - y = w$?

Comment: But can we not assume that there is x+3=z and 4−y=w?

Comment: My point was just that if we can find $x$ and $y$ so that $x + 3 = z$ and $4 - y = w$, then we can show $f$ is surjective, because we'd have $f(x, y) = (z, w)$ like we want. We don't need to assume such $x$ and $y$ exist, we can solve the equations I wrote to figure out exactly what they have to be.